# multiple broadcast receiver are not called its unfortunately stopped app

Tags: android

its unfortunately stooped when i connect charger or disconnect the charger, **code are as below**

```
public int onStartCommand(Intent intent, int flags, int startId)
    {

        connectreceiver myPowerConnectedBCReceiver = new connectreceiver();
        IntentFilter intentPowerOnFilter = new IntentFilter();
        intentPowerOnFilter.addAction("android.intent.action.ACTION_POWER_CONNECTED");
        registerReceiver(myPowerConnectedBCReceiver, intentPowerOnFilter);

        BroadcastReceiver PowerConnectedReceiver = new BroadcastReceiver() 
        {
            @Override
            public void onReceive(Context context, Intent intent) {
                Toast.makeText(context,"Connected",Toast.LENGTH_LONG);
            }
        };


        //      Handle Power Off
        disconnectreceiver myPowerDisonnectedBCReceiver = new disconnectreceiver();
        IntentFilter intentPowerDisconnectedOnFilter = new IntentFilter();
        intentPowerDisconnectedOnFilter.addAction("android.intent.action.ACTION_POWER_DISCONNECTED");
        registerReceiver(myPowerDisonnectedBCReceiver, intentPowerDisconnectedOnFilter);

        BroadcastReceiver PowerDisconnectedReceiver = new BroadcastReceiver() {
            @Override
            public void onReceive(Context context, Intent intent) {
                Toast.makeText(context, "Disconnected", Toast.LENGTH_LONG);
            }
        };
        return super.onStartCommand(intent, flags, startId);
    }
```

Comment: post the error logcat

Comment: not log cat its unfortunately stooped when connect or disconnect the charger

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Register your receiver in onCreate method.

Comment: this code is placed in the service then how code can placed and i aso try in oncreate() method of myactivity class

Comment: @Mayank, Is it works?

Answer (score 0):

the easy way is to create a class **PowerConnectedReceiver** as an "BroadcastReceiver" and declare it on your manifest file like code below

```
<receiver android:name=".PowerConnectedReceiver">
            <intent-filter>
                <action android:name="android.intent.action.ACTION_POWER_CONNECTED" />
            </intent-filter>
        </receiver>
```

the **PowerConnectedReceiver** code like the code below

```
public class PowerConnectedReceiverextends BroadcastReceiver {

    @Override
    public void onReceive(Context context, Intent intent) {
         //start your service or do what you want her
         //Intent service = new Intent(context, MyService.class);
         //context.startService(intent);
    }
}
```

**I hope this help you**

Comment: i also create two class as same and added in to the menifest file but still i get unfortunately stopped app and error are in this code and PowerConnectedReceiver and PowerDisconnectedReceiver   object are display as unused object

Comment: did you comment your logcat error